# Is there a way to comment inside a Twine Localization file?

Tags: ios, localization, localizable.strings

I've started using this sweet script [Twine](https://github.com/mobiata/twine) to help manage localizations. it makes it really easy to have specific comments about your localizations like:

```
[[Settings]]
    [Contact]
        en = Contact
        comment = Settings Section Header
```

But I'm wonder if there is a way to use general comments in the files. I've tried a few common ones that aren't working like:

```
[[Settings]]
# This is a Comment
// This is a Comment
    [Contact]
        en = Contact
        comment = Settings Section Header
```

Both cause the script to crash and fail.

Comment: Just a wild guess: the syntax of Twine is based on Windows `.ini` files, and in `.ini` files comment lines start with a semicolon (`;`). Could you give that a try?

Comment: Found out its not actually supported. Its currently sitting as a low priority feature request. https://github.com/mobiata/twine/issues/8

Comment: You should post that comment as an answer...

Comment: Yea I guess a month later no more answers are coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone comes looking. As of today, its not supported. There is an issue tracking the feature. They are currently looking for someone to implement it. It doesn't look to be a simple task. Because the strings.txt files are read/write, the parser would need to take comments into account at multiple points of the process. And if lines were added the parser would need to know where to put the comment in relation.

You can follow along the development here: https://github.com/mobiata/twine/issues/8